# Scala build.sbt и import utest

Tags: scala

Установил sbt и плагин скала, могу создавать классы скала, но в build.sbt все красное и не могу utest импортировать.В чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image]

Comment: Перенесите исходник в `src/test` (не `src/main`)

Comment: главное, что import utest._  не работает.  А import Exercises._  заработало.

Comment: Я думаю, сто с built.sbt какая-то проблема, а импорт с тестами это следствие.

Comment: "проблема" с `% test`. Если хотите, чтобы импорты работали не только в тестах - уберите это.

Comment: это тоже не помогло